# Two way SSL/TLS with Self Signed Certificate and no CA

Tags: ssl, java

**Imaginary data sharing App 'ABC' written in Java works like this:**

1. When started for the first time it generates a self signed certificate and maintains its own KeyStore and TrustStore.
2. When App 'ABC' from another computer initiates a connection for the first time this will send the certificate (as it is server) to 'ABC' in other computer. Other app asks the user whether to trust this certificate. User accepts to trusts the certificate permanently (communicates externally and allow the App to add) and the certificate will be added to its (App in computer B) trust store.

**Issue 1**

The client (App in computer B) does not send its certificate (as it is client).

**Attempted Solution 1**

From Google search i learned that

1. i need to do below code changes

   ```
   // After creating SSLServerSocket
   serverSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
   ```
2. Also return a CA certificate as part of custom TrustManager's [getAcceptedIssuers()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html#getAcceptedIssuers--) method

**Issue 2**

Now the problem is i don't have CA certificate. Also embedding the self signed CA certificate with private key doesn't seem to make much sense (or is it OK?).

Is there any other solution to the problem?

Comment: With self-signed certificate, usually the self-signed certificate itself acts both as the CA certificate and the user certificate. However if your question is more about Java programming than a general IT security question, it may be more suitable on [so].

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf It is related to both Java and Security. Was not sure which is better place.

Comment: It depends on the kind of answer you expect: if this is code snipets or recommendations to use this class or this method, then this is definitively Stack Overflow, if you want to understand the mechanisms or the reason behind a certain feature or issue and just use Java as an example but don't expect any code in any language as answer, then it could better fit here. With overlapping subjects it is indeed sometimes hard to find the right website ;). I've voted to migrate your question to SO, once enough votes have been casted it will be automatically migrated there.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf ok with StackOverflow, i don't see any option to do it myself.  If self signed certificate is used as CA how the other party knows about it? Just trust it for the first time? or the certificate file should be externally transferred? (i want to avoid this)

Comment: With self signed certificate you have no other choice than trust it the first time. Usually this involves a manual process where the application shows a fingerprint of the certificate to the user, asking him if he trusts this currently unknown certificate. If security matters the user should have received a copy of the expected fingerprint out-of-band (by fax, from hand-to-hand, etc.) so he can compare the one displayed by the software with the one expected and trust the self-signed certificate only if both match.